# Hiding table in html without hiding images

Tags: html

let me just say that I'm by no means a professional programmer, I know a bit of css and html, enough for what I need to do for work.

I used table generator and then inserted links and images needed for my page. I used table to keep images in order and now I'd like to remove table without removing image and img properties but cant find a way to do that.

I'm sorry if this was questioned nad answered somewhere, I couldnt find it anywhere on the internet.

For some reason I cant paste part of the code I want

Comment: Please try again to paste your code here. We can not help without it.

Comment: Do you wish to hide the table border ?

Comment: <style type="text/css">table.tftable {font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:100%;border-width: 0px;border-color: #729ea5;border-collapse: collapse;}
table.tftable th {font-size:12px;background-color:#acc8cc;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #729ea5;text-align:left;}
table.tftable tr {background-color:#ffffff;}
table.tftable td {font-size:12px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;}
</style>

Comment: Not sure why it goes out like this, like I said Im just new to all this.
I can give you a link so you can inspect the page if you wish.
http://www.intercars-sajam.hr/#/pridruzite_nam_se